# List of chars to string in Emacs Lisp

Tags: string, emacs, elisp, concatenation, chars

I have a list of characters `(?h ?e ?l ?l ?o)` and i want to convert it to string `"hello"`. Currently i use this structure:

```
(concat (mapcar (lambda (ch) (char-to-string ch)) s))
```

Is there a more elegant and idiomatic way to **convert list of chars to a string** in Elisp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Elisp's `concat` returns a string:

```
(concat '(?h ?e ?l ?l ?o))
```

(Found it out from `coerce` implementation in `cl`)

Answer (score 7):

There's also `(apply #'string LIST-OF-CHARS)`.

Comment: On my version of emacs (version 24.4) this also works without `#` as `(apply 'string LIST-OF-CHARS)`